# How to access window.crypto in vscode extension (electron)?

Tags: dom, visual-studio-code, cryptography, window, electron

I'm building a webview **extension on visual studio code** for my web app and I'm doing some cryptography manipulations using the browser's **window.crypto lib**.

I would like to do the same thing inside my vscode extension but **I can't find the crypto library nor the DOM window**. I know that it runs under electron which uses Chromium so I thought there might be a way to access this library.